# Inverse of a matrix with one value on the diagonal and another value off the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let us look at the the matrix

$$ M =\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & \dots  & b      \\
b & a  & \dots  & b    \\
\vdots & b  & \ddots & \vdots \\
b  & \dots & b  & a
\end{bmatrix}$$

It has one value $a$ on the main diagonal, and another value $b$ everywhere else. Let us assume that $a \neq b$.
I wish to find the inverse of every $n\times n$ matrix of this form ($a$ on the diagonal, $b$ everywhere else).

Comment: give me a link of that post?

Comment: Just look to the right. It’s the very first related question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/561047/321264

Answer (score 2):

Write $M=(a-b)I+bJ$ where $J$ is the all-one matrix. Try an inverse also
of this form $N=xI+yJ$. Taking $I=MN$ will give you two equations in $x$
and $y$ which should be easily soluble.

Comment: i don't understand your answer.can you briefly tell me the answer.thanks

Comment: What do you get when you expand out $((a-b)I+bJ)(xI+yJ)$? @jadey

Comment: i don't know how to expand this.can you expand this for me,and tell me why you take M=(a-b)I + bJ , N = xI+yJ ?

Comment: @jadey Note that $J^2=nJ$.

Comment: @egreg can you provide me complete answer briefly?